# Apache Httppost retrieve image from server Java

Tags: java, apache, http-post

Right now I am using Httppost to Post some parameters in the form of xml to a server. When the post occurs, a geotiff or .tif file is downloaded. I have successfully posted the document to the server and successfully downloaded the file simply by attaching the parameters to the url but I can't seem to combine the two. I have to use post because just using the URL leaves out elevation data in the geotiff.

In short, I am not sure how to simultaneously post and retrieve the image of the post. This is what I have thus far...

```
// Get target URL
        String strURL = POST;

        // Get file to be posted
        String strXMLFilename = XML_PATH;
        File input = new File(strXMLFilename);

        // Prepare HTTP post
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(strURL);

        post.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(
                new FileInputStream(input), input.length()));

        // Specify content type and encoding
        post.setHeader(
                "Content-type", "text/xml");

        // Get HTTP client
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Locate file to store data in
        FileEntity entity = new FileEntity(newTiffFile, ContentType.create("image/geotiff"));

        post.setEntity(entity);

        // Execute request
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to Metoc site...\n");

            HttpResponse result = httpclient.execute(post);
```

I was under the impression that the entity would contain the resulting image. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: you are calling `post.setEntity` twice and the second overwrites the first call (I think). Do you want to send then both to the server? Downloading usually means to read a response from the server.

Comment: hmm that may actually be part of the issue because I have code that is reading from the response but maybe the issue is in the entity. I was reading some documentation that made me think the entity was what I would download. It must be what is added to the post.

Comment: The entity is part of the request, which is *send* *to* the server. If you want to read data from the server, read it from the response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. The entity was what was being sent to the server. I had code that was trying to read it from the response as well but it wasn't working because setting the entity to a file entity messed up the post request. By removing that part, it works great!